# How to use "SELECT IN" in EF5

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I sent this rare query, I really have difficulty being able to pass it to ef, can you please give me a hand with it?

Thank you very much in advance

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    Company c
    JOIN [User] u ON c.id = u.id_company
WHERE
    (
        ( u.id_usertype = 3 )
        AND
        ( u.id = 2135 )
    )

UNION

SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    Company c
    JOIN Company mc ON c.id_company = mc.id
WHERE
    mc.id in
    (
        SELECT
            c.id
        FROM
            Company c
            JOIN [User] u ON c.id = u.id_company 
        WHERE
        (
            ( u.id_usertype = 3 )
            AND
            ( u.id = 2135 )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Why aren't you using EF6?

Comment: @Dai There are plenty of reasons why one wouldn't be able to use `x version` of some software. Not sure how that's related to the question

Comment: Your query is using the `WHERE IN` as a JOIN filter. Your query can be rewritten without the `WHERE IN` statement and using another JOIN.

Comment: @Rob EF6 is far more powerful and flexible than EF5 and is generally backwards-compatible with EF5's API. I stopped working with EF5 years ago and I don't know if any recommendation I have will work with EF5 and not EF6.

Comment: I'm going over this query and it seems braindead, frankly - I assume `User.id` is the primary key for the `Users` table, so the majority of this query can be replaced with a single query and a single trivial `WHERE` clause, there is no need even for a UNION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've explained the Subcompany/Company relationship I see that the query can be changed to the query below:

```
SELECT
    Company.*
FROM
    [User]
    INNER JOIN Company ON [User].id_company = Company.id
WHERE
    [User].id = 2135

UNION

SELECT
    SubCompany .*
FROM
    [User]
    INNER JOIN Company ON [User].id_company = Company.id
    INNER JOIN Company AS SubCompany ON Company.id = SubCompany.id_company
WHERE
    [User].id = 2135
```

This `UNION`-based query can be simplified into the single query below by changing the `INNER JOIN Company As SubCompany` so it uses an `OR` so it matches both the original company and the sub-companies.

```
SELECT
    SubCompany.*
FROM
    [User]
    INNER JOIN Company ON [User].id_company = Company.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Company AS SubCompany ON
    (
        Company.id = SubCompany.id_company
        OR
        Company.id = SubCompany.id
    )
WHERE
    [User].id = 2135
```

However, in Linq you cannot use complex `JOIN` criteria if you're using Navigation Properties (you can if you use Linq's `GroupBy` or `Join` operations), so we must fall-back to a `UNION` via the `Concat` operation:

I assume you have a `Company->SubCompany` relationship defined in Entity Framework, in which case you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var query = dbContext
    .Users
    .Where( u => u.id == 2135 )
    .Select( u => u.Company )
    .Concat(
        dbContext
            .Users
            .Where( u => u.id == 2135 )
            .SelectMany( u => u.Company.SubCompanies )
    );
```